# Ring without 1 of least power, not isomorphic to its opposite

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let us introduce the concept of an opposite ring.

$\textbf{Def}$: Ring $R^{opp}$, opposite to $R$, is a ring with the same Abelian addition group, the multiplication in which $\cdot_{opp}$ is performed in reverse order: $x \cdot_{opp} y = y \cdot x$

I want to try to build a ring $R$ without $1$ of least power, not isomorphic to its opposite.

If $R \cong R^{opp}$ then there is a homomorphism $\varphi$ such that for any $x, y \in R$ we have:
$$
\varphi(x \cdot y) = \varphi(x) \cdot_{opp} \varphi(y) = \varphi(y) \cdot \varphi(x) = \varphi(y \cdot x).
$$
This means that for there to be no isomorphism, the ring $R$ must be non-commutative.
Let's consider $R = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \mathbb{Z}_2 \\ \mathbb{Z}_2 & \mathbb{Z}_2\end{bmatrix}$.
$E \notin R$ and $R$ is non-commutative. There are only 8 elements in $R$. Can we imagine an example of a ring with fewer elements?

Comment: If you remove the $E_{12}$ entry you get a 4-element rng with same property. Can you see why 2- and 3-element rngs are commutative and thus isomorphic to their opposites?

Comment: Your ring $R$ is isomorphic to its opposite via the transpose operation.

Comment: Actually, $R$ is not a ring, since $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\not\in R$.

Answer (score 0):

The mathoverflow question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64370/simplest-examples-of-rings-that-are-not-isomorphic-to-their-opposites has a couple of answers. The answer by Frieder Ladisch mentions a ring with 16 elements:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
       \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \\
         0                    & \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}
   \end{pmatrix}$$

I don't know if it is the smallest example, though.

Comment: PS: it took me 5 seconds of googling to find this.

Comment: But $1 = E$ belongs to this ring

Comment: Ah ok I was assuming that you just want a ring that is not necessarily unital